Help unpacking Schrödinger's Hamiltonian
I found out that the time-independent Schrödinger's equation in one dimension is just a special case of a Sturm-Liouville problem, but in every source I can only see the hamiltonian formulation:
$$\hat{\mathbf{H}}|\Psi\rangle=E|\Psi\rangle$$
I don't really understand what the hamiltonian operator means in QM... Still, I would like to gain some intuition about what the equation is mathematically doing, so I would like to see the Sturm-Liouville form of it. Can anyone help with that?

In non-relativistic QM it is the sum of kinetic and potential energy.

You should have NO difficulty at all finding the equation in derivatives of wavefunction form. It is exactly a Sturm-Liouville problem.

In Schrödinger's equation, the Hamiltonian is just
$$
\hat{H} = \hat{T} + \hat{V},
$$
where $\hat{T}$ and $\hat{V}$ are the kinetic and potential energy of the system, respectively.
Usually we work in the wavefunction representation, where we define $\Psi(\vec{x}) := \left<\vec{x} \right.\left|\Psi \right>$.
In the one particle system, for coordinate space, these are
$$
\hat{T} = \dfrac{\hat{\vec{p}}^2}{2m}, \quad \text{and} \quad \hat{V} = V(\vec{x}),
$$
where the momentum operator takes the form $\hat{\vec{p}} = -i\hbar\vec{\nabla}$. With this, the Hamiltonian becomes
$$
-\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 + V(\vec{x}),
$$
which can easily be generalised to the $N$-particle Hamiltonian. From here you can already see the S-L equation!
As a side comment, $\hat{V}$ cannot depend on time, as you are dealing with the time independent Schrödinger equation. If your equation is instead the more general
$$
\hat{H}\left|\Psi (t) \right> = -i\hbar\partial_t \left|\Psi (t)\right>,
$$
which for the wavefunction is
$$
\hat{H} \Psi (t,\vec{x})  = -i\hbar\partial_t \Psi (t,\vec{x}),
$$
then $\hat{V} = V(t,\vec{x})$ is allowed.

So, making $\hat{H}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+ V(\vec{x})$ i get the usual Sturm-
Liouville operator, isn't it? Thanks!

Precisely! No problem.
